# Why the post content editor always expanded?

Tags: visual-editor

I'm having my wordpress post editor always expanded, and i don't like this and don't no why it has been turned into this. How to disable this auto expansion?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure i understand what you mean by 'expanded' but look into those two options, i think it will solve your problem.

[image]

Comment: No not this.. I mean the text editor itself it is expanded with no side bar to move up or down

Comment: maybe add a screenshot to be more understandable.